# Checkbox is always "checked"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an HTML form and defined an checkbox for that.

My sample code for this:

```
<label class="checkbox inline" >
    <input type="checkbox"  id="http" name="HTTP"  <%=transport_http%>/>
    <input type="hidden" id="http_checked" name="http_checked" value= <%if(transport_http == "checked"){%>"http"<%}else{%>""<%}%>/>
</label>
```

Here I always get the value as "checked" even if I uncheck the box. What might be the wrong?

I read my hidden variable parameter in a javascript like;

```
var transport =request.getParameter("http_checked")
```

For this varibale i always get value as "http". (even if i checked or not checked the box) why is that?

Comment: Why do you have a hidden input there at all? (And the value of the *checkbox* is never going to be checked, since you didn't specify a value attribute it will only ever be `on` if it is set at all.)

Comment: i'll read that hidden value in javascript to check my checkbox value Eg: var transport =request.getParameter("http_checked") Now what is the wrong in my page?

Comment: That variable will never reflect the current state of the checkbox. It will reflect that state of `transport_http` (which doesn't depend on the the state of the checkbox). Your code doesn't make any sense. It will also never have the value `http` since that isn't one of the two values your code sets it too.

Comment: @Quentin what? No, [Checkboxes don't need a value attribute in order to work](http://jsfiddle.net/8gk3ucbb/) (it also doesn't make any sense). You other comment is spot on though

Comment: @Ratha you're not always getting a checked value, you're just getting the value from the hidden input because there's nothing that connects the checkbox and hidden input to each other - they are both independent of each other. As Quentin said, the whole setup doesn't make too much sense, so we can't exactly "correct" it because frankly, we're not sure what you're trying to achieve. To me it seems like you can probably ditch the hidden input entirely and rely on the checkbox

Comment: @Yuvi tahnks a lot, i skipped that hidden variable and made like my html page like; <label  class="checkbox inline" >
                           <input type="checkbox"  id="transport_http" name="transport_http"  value="http" />
                        
                         
                       </label> and reading the value as request.getParameter("transport_http")) looks like working as expected..BTW, my usecase just an html page(jsp) and provide two checkboxes to read whether the protocol is http/https and pass that to backend

Comment: Ok, happy to have helped I guess. Just remember that inputs are independent of each other, and if you want them linked together - something needs to make sure of that (client-side javascript, some server-side analysis etc..)

Comment: @yuvi — I never said that checkboxes had to have a value. I said that if you didn't set a value attribute then the value would be `on`.

Comment: @Ratha – I can't correct it. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

I corrected as follows:

```
 <div class="checkbox">
                       <label  class="checkbox inline" >
                           <input type="checkbox"  id="transport_http" name="transport_http"  value="http" />

                       </label>
                       <label  class="checkbox inline" >
                           <input type="checkbox"  id="transport_https" name="transport_https"  value="https"/>


                       </label>
                   </div>
```

And reading the value in a javascript like

```
request.getParameter("transport_https"),request.getParameter("transport_http")
```

works

Comment: isn't that *Java* instead of javascript?

Comment: It is a jS function (server side javascript function, similar to javascript, but our custom librray) which i use to read those checkbox params

Comment: Really? I thought it was a `jsp` thing, and that server-side javascript is only used by node.js

Comment: You can check this site, we have library called jaggery, you can try out:) http://jaggeryjs.org/

Comment: Thank you, I just might (though I'm pretty happy with Django for now). Here's a small pro tip - you guys should remove that nicescroll plugin, it's terribly unnatural, especially so when webkit-based browsers allow you style the scroll natively....

Comment: @yuvi — There are [many SSJS implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions) that are not Node.